# time.Time.Sub() miscalculation after system sleep

Tags: go

I created a [timer application](https://github.com/drgrib/ttimer) to be run in a terminal window.

I'm witnessing some strange behavior in [`time.Time.Sub()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Sub) when I start a terminal timer and put my macOS laptop running it to sleep by closing it.

When I reopen the laptop, suddenly the function appears to not work properly, as tracked by [this block of code](https://github.com/drgrib/ttimer/blob/3f368e3fca45cba809e1e0574311b1f8d7266d97/agent/agent.go#L50), which can be seen in this copied output to miscalculate unless I am misunderstanding the `time.Time` values:

```
== 615a Timer ==
20m59s

now: 2018-04-27 05:58:20.440440541 -0700 PDT m=+310.234277006
exactLeft: 20m59.142673336s
t.end: 2018-04-27 06:15:00.000129434 -0700 PDT m=+1569.376950342
t.end.Sub(now): 20m59.142673336s
```

Explicitly, `now` is set to `5:58` and `t.end` is set to `6:15`, which has a duration of `17m`. Yet, `t.end.Sub(now)` evaluates to `21m`, which is a difference of about the time that my laptop was asleep. What is happening here?

Comment: The screenshot looks like it's cropped on the right hand side. Also what OS? Do you see the same problem with a different language. I've experienced weird time issues with Windows after coming out of hibernation.

Comment: @StevieB Good points. I've updated the question to have clearer output and specified my OS. I'm using macOS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is caused I believe by the difference between wall clock and monotonic clock, both of which may or may not be held inside the `Time` variables. Different methods on `Time` variables give different results depending on presence or absence of monotonic clock. I'm not sure of all the ins and outs, and it changed in Go 1.9 I think, but it's documented at the top of the time package and in the godoc.

I think there may also be some differences dependent on how the specific OS treats monotonic clock. I suspect that the print statement is printing wall clock values but the `Sub` method is using monotonic.

Try stripping monotonic clock from one of your Time variables using `now = now.Round(0)` before calling `Sub`. That should fix it by forcing it to use wall clock.

Comment: Wow. What a fascinating issue. That was it. Thanks for the cue to read the top of the `time` package godoc. It answered both this question and what the `m=` notation in the `time.Time.String()` means.